# Not able to write left outer join for same table query in MS Access database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, join

I have my table in my ma access as [image]

I am retrieving the data from sql database with the query

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
     dbo.Tree.pname
    ,dbo.Tree.SlNo AS PNum
    ,dbo.Tree.pname AS CName
    ,dbo.Tree.Prnt
FROM dbo.Tree
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tree AS Ptr_AcntInfo_1 ON dbo.Tree.Prnt = Tree.SlNo
WHERE Tree.Ref = 155
ORDER BY dbo.Tree.Prnt;
```

It is working well when I am retrieving from sql databse(The table structure is same in MS Access and SQL Database).

When I am retrieving the data from MS Access database with the same query it is showing error
as `The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.`

I want the same query from MS Access database. Help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (`TOP (100) PERCENT` and I think also `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary) -

```
SELECT
      t.pname
    , t.SlNo AS PNum
    , t.pname AS CName
    , t.Prnt
FROM Tree AS t
--LEFT OUTER JOIN Tree AS t2 ON t.Prnt = t2.SlNo
WHERE t.Ref = 155
ORDER BY t.Prnt
```

Comment: Sorryy.. It is showing a different error as Could not find file "'C:\Thalassemia\Bloodbank\bin\Release\dbo.mdb'." Actually I have connected with network in my company.

Comment: got it ... Thak you verrrrrrrrrrrrrrry much